Population of amoeba and extinction at the $n$th minute
Suppose in a pond, there is a single amoeba and every minute, it has equal $1/3$ chance of dying, doing nothing, or splitting into two. Assume that all the new amoeba behave just like the original one and they do not influence each other (and that the pond is able to contain an arbitrary number of them). Of course, once an amoeba is dead, it can no longer do anything.
I would like to know what the probability $p_n$ of the amoeba extinction at minute $t=n$ is in terms of other $p_i$ for $i \leq n-1$. In doing so, $p_{\leq n} := \sum^n_{i=0} p_i$ should give the probability of extinction at or before $t=n$.
At first, I thought that there should be a simple recursive relation. If $p:=p_{\leq \infty}$ is the probability of eventual extinction, then I think we can show that $p=\frac{1}{3}(1+p+p^2)$ and $p=1$ is the only algebraic solution (with multiplicity 2). So the amoeba will eventually go extinct.
Thus, at first I thought $p_n=\frac{1}{3}(1+p_{n-1}+p^2_{n-1})$ for all $n$ but that can't be right because after computing a few, $p_1+p_2+p_3> 1$ and in hindsight, that's obvious since I'd defined $p$ cumulatively. Could it be that $p_{\leq n}=\frac{1}{3}(1+p_{\leq n-1}+p^2_{\leq n-1})$, instead? Then $p_n=p_{\leq n} - p_{\leq n-1}$.
Actually, even better, I'd like to know $a(k,n)$, the probability of having $k$ amoeba by minute $n$ either just in terms of $k,n$ (which is likely complicated) or in terms of $a(i,m)$ where $i$ can be anything but $m\leq n-1$. Then $p_n = a(0,n)$. But this may be quite difficult.
There are similar questions asked here on StackExchange but I'm fairly new to probability and so I'd appreciate more elementary explanations if possible.

Your first recurrence relation on $p_n$ is not correct, because if for example the first branch in the family tree is extinct after $n-1$ steps, and the second branch dies after $n-2$ steps, you still need $n$ steps in total for the full ameoba population to be extinct. Your second recurrence relation is correct though.

Thanks! Do you have a proof of why the 2nd relation is correct?

You're welcome ! This is because for the population to be extinct before $n$ steps, one of three things must happen:

The first amoeba dies (prob $1/3$).
The first amoeba survives on the first turn, and then the population takes less than $n-1$ steps to extinct (prob $1/3 \times p_{\le n-1}$).
The first amoeba duplicates, and then all the descendants of the two new amoebas are extinct in less than $n-1$ turns. These can be seen as two new population of amoebas, hence the probability is $1/3 \times p_{\le n-1} \times p_{\le n-1}$.


Sum everything and factorize. This yields your formula.
